# SharePoint: "Failed to extract the cab file in the solution"

Tags: sharepoint, deployment

I'm receiving a "Failed to extract the cab file in the solution" error when I try to deploy my wsp using stsadm -o addsolution -filename...

I've open the wsp as a cab and checked that there are no duplicate files in there as I understand that can sometimes cause this issue.

The issue only started when I tried to include a custom field type as part of my solution, to do this I added the following to the ddf

..\CustomFields\ShortMonth\ShortMonthControl.ascx ..\CONTROLTEMPLATES\ShortMonthControl.ascx

..\CustomFields\ShortMonth\fldtypes_shortmonth.xml ..\XML\fldtypes_shortmonth.xml

and

`<TemplateFiles`>

`<TemplateFile Location="CONTROLTEMPLATES\ShortMonthControl.ascx"/`>

`<TemplateFile Location="XML\fldtypes_shortmonth.xml"/>`

`</TemplateFiles>`

to the manifest.

I've tried taking it back to just references to the ascx in both but it doesn't see to help.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need the "..\" in your DDF?

Comment: (+1)This was what I was after in my answer...just didn´t remember it.

Answer (score 7):

Check that you don't have any special characters in your files. They might have sneaked in as a result of copy-paste. For example, the way your code sample renders on this page, it has the (`), which shouldn't be there.

Comment: Checked there aren't any special chars in the source (edited original question as some stuff had come into StackOverflow wrongly when pasting it from Outlook)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is more likely due to invalid names for files you are deploying on SharePoint 14 hive folder. If you are using parenthesis  ‘(‘, ‘)’ in file names or special characters like @ in file names, this issue will occur.

Remove it and issue should vanish.

Answer (score 0):

I just know I have had the same issues and I think I made a note of it at work somewhere (I´ll check that tomorrow and post back here if I find something). I just can´t remember how I fixed it right now (maybe it was a slash the wrong way / vs. \..hmm). 
I did a search for it on google (which I think you have also done). Found this (check it out):

http://www.codeplex.com/wspbuilder/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=7385

Answer (score 0):

The List Instance Name I had was "MyListInstance (List Instance)". I removed the brackets from the name and it deployed without issues.

Answer (score 0):

Check the .ddf file for a line that could have been accidentally duplicated. Apparently sharepoint doesn't like that!

Answer (score 0):

A reboot solved my 'Failed to extract cab file' problem. There were some updates installed and an reboot was required. Was not clear that this was related but it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Something would have gone wrong during the build of WSP.
Re build the WSP and Deploy- it should work fine.